# VBA Code to reference cell as name when choosing paste destination worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone help me modify this code so that it can reference the data in cell A6 and paste to the sheet named after that data.

I already have a working macro for pasting data from a cover sheet to individual worksheets, each day, and without overwriting previously populated cells (See below).

The issue is that the code is too specific and is not easily manipulated when new rows are introduced to the "Balancer" cover-sheet. Here is an example of the current code:

```
Sub pastetosheet()

 r = 1
Sheets("Balancer").Range("B2").Copy
Sheets("X9X9USDFEDT6").Range("C35").End(xlUp).Offset(r, 0).PasteSpecial _
    paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheets("Balancer").Range("D2").Copy
Sheets("X9X9USDFEDT6").Range("D35").End(xlUp).Offset(r, 0).PasteSpecial _
    paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheets("Balancer").Range("F2").Copy
Sheets("X9X9USDFEDT6").Range("F35").End(xlUp).Offset(r, 0).PasteSpecial _
    paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Sheets("Balancer").Range("G2").Copy
Sheets("X9X9USDFEDT6").Range("H35").End(xlUp).Offset(r, 0).PasteSpecial _
    paste:=xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

I want the code to copy data in Range "B6" on the "Balancer" tab, then reference the data in the cell to the left (A6 in this case) to find out which sheet it will be pasting to. Then use the paste rules already in place from the current code.

Comment: So each cell of column `A` names a different sheet. or only `A6` has the target sheet's name?

Comment: each cell in column A is named after a different sheet where the data in columns B, D, F, G needs to paste to.

Answer (score 1):

If each row specifies its own destination sheet in column `A`, this should do:

```
Sub pasteToSheetOfA()
    Dim r As Long, t As Range
    With Sheets("Balancer")
        For r = 1 To .Range("B1000000").End(xlUp).Row ' for all rows of column B

            ' get the target sheet specified in column A, goto beyond last cell in C of this sheet
            Set t = Sheets(.Range("A" & r).value).Range("C1000000").End(xlUp).Offset(1)

            ' now copy the cells of the row according to the rules of the OP
            t.value = .Cells(r, "B").value
            t.Offset(,1).value = .Cells(r, "D").value
            t.Offset(,3).value = .Cells(r, "F").value
            t.Offset(,5).value = .Cells(r, "G").value
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice code, but add some explanation and comments to your code (you do remember that people asking for assitance here are not VBA experts)

Comment: @ShaiRado you're right, I'm a bit lazy maybe, but I was waiting the comments of the OP to add explanations accordingly :)

Comment: I added some explanation.